# Why is my phone WiFi keep disconnecting and reconnecting when playing games?

Tags: wi-fi

The device I used is Realme C2 and there's no problem about my WiFi except my games. If I open the apps that uses more bandwidth it never disconnected, while if I use games like Minecraft Bedrock then I connected to a Minecraft server which have 30ms ping then it starts to disconnecting and reconnecting every 5 - 10 minutes. And now my gaming experience is impacted.
And again, I use other apps and the WiFi is fine and not disconnecting. My distance from router is 3 meters and I have full WiFi signal.

I forget all networks, clear cache, restarted my phone but still okay EXCEPT ONE which is games keep disconnecting and reconnecting.

I have another phone and connect to same network it fine even in games but in my phone Realme C2 is a problem when I play games.

Video:
https://youtu.be/854mOZhAAHQ

Comment: Do you use your phone often in landscape mode? May be Wifi disconnects because your hands are shielding the Wifi signal (the water in the human body can weaken the signal, especially if you hold your hands close to the antenna).

Comment: Or did the phone get hot? The temperature may also affect hardware performance, including the WiFi chip.